# Asynchronous NSURLConnection and NSOperation - cancelling

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to cancel all requests. Here is how I'm creating asynchronous connection:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:echo queue:self.queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *respone, NSData *data, NSError *error){
```

I then use this method:

```
-(void)cancelAllRequests
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.queue.operations);
    [self.queue cancelAllOperations];
    [self.queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}
```

to cancel all requests.

Which actually doesn't do anything except changing a BOOL to YES.

So how I'm supposed to cancel an asynchronous connection?

Answer (score 5):

You *can't* cancel connections scheduled using `sendAsynchronousRequest`. The queue you're referring to is only used for scheduling the completion hander.

If you want full control of the `NSURLConnection`, you'll have to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` yourself. An example implementation can be found on https://gist.github.com/3794804

Comment: I'll share a gist to this in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put Synchronous requests into an Operation (using a block).

The set the NSOperationQueue maxNumberOfConcurrentOperations to 1 (so they run one at a time).

Then if you run cancelAllOperations on the queue it will stop any operations that haven't run yet.